What is the use of .gitignore in a GitHub Repo?
I have been using git since the last few months. I came cross .gitignore. Can anyone please guide regarding the purposes and usage of .gitignore?
I did a little bit of research and found that its about "file tracking". But I also don't know what file tracking is!

.gitignore quite simply tells git to ignore certain files. It won't track, commit, or push them.
Typically, you want to use this for secrets, or things that don't need to be pushed (such as dependencies).
For example, if I have a bunch of files in my git directory, but also have a .env file that has secrets (such as API keys) that I don't want to be public, I could add that file to my .gitignore. Then, any time I commit, that file isn't committed or pushed, it remains only on my device.
As for file tracking, that's just which files git is keeping a version history of. If a file is untracked, then git isn't keeping an eye on changes, and if you make a commit untracked files won't be committed. A tracked file, on the other hand, has its history stored by git.

.gitignore basically tells Git to ignore certain files (such as .env, dependencies, etc.) when you push a directory to GitHub. If you open .gitignore file on your code editor and take a look at it, you will understand better.
